# Regarding SegmentSmack and Fragmentsmack vulnerability Fix

Tags: 14.04

This is regarding SegmentSmack and Fragmentsmack vulnerability.
I have a couple of Ubuntu servers with 14.04 and kernel 4.2.0-42-generic. So can anyone guide me how to fix the vulnerability?

Is there any patch or update available.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  First I would `full-upgrade` your system, as the 4.2 kernel reached EOL on August 2016, and has not been supported since then by Canonical/Ubuntu. It was used by 14.04.4, and was replaced by kernel 4.4 when you upgraded to 14.04.5 (*with HWE enabled; 3.13 is still supported if you didn't use/enable HWE*).  Upgrade your system with `sudo apt dist-upgrade` or `sudo apt full-upgrade` and don't use an unsupported/EOL kernel.

Comment: Thank you. Could you share me any related link to upgrade

Comment: You needn't do anything but normal dist-upgrade(s). Your system hasn't been upgraded (with `full-upgrade` or `dist-upgrade`) in years given your kernel (unless you `apt-mark` an EOL kernel which was risky, so you've not got the latest security fixes.

Comment: ok. So i need to update the kernal latest one or upgrade to ubuntu 16

Comment: What is the fix for this vulnerability.

Comment: A normal `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` should take you to the latest kernel (4.4) & 14.04.5 which includes the patch mentioned in my answer.  If you're running 14.04.4 (kernel 4.2) you've not done this since mid-late 2016; so you should do this [dist-upgrade] more often !

Comment: fyi:  `sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade` only upgrades some packages; within rules mentioned in the manual (`man apt`) which excludes many upgrades including kernel patches.  A `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` or `sudo apt full-upgrade` "*in addition to performing the function of upgrade, also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions of packages...*"  (copied from `man apt-get`)

Answer (score 0):

I would full-upgrade your system, as the 4.2 kernel reached EOL on August 2016 (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support), and has not been supported since then by Canonical/Ubuntu. It was used by 14.04.4, and was replaced by kernel 4.4 when you upgraded to 14.04.5 (with HWE enabled; 3.13 is still supported if you didn't use/enable HWE).

Upgrade your system with

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

or

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

and don't use an unsupported/EOL kernel.

As per your flaw - refer https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2018/CVE-2018-5390.html where you'll note it was fixed in the 3.13 & 4.4 kernels.